# How to open a file via the default program from the JTable in Java

Tags: java, arrays, swing, file, jtable

I'm trying to make a program. However, I'm not doing very well.

**My program is realized in this way:**

- VSM (Contains the path and file name as attributes)
- Book(Contains attributes of type String and Object VSM class)
- Library (The library    actually contains ArrayList objects of the
  book class)

It is all written in a table and through this code the selected file should be opened, however I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The file: C:\file.pdf doesn't exist.
```

This is my code:

```
tabelaKnjiga_T.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
        JTable jt = (JTable) evt.getSource();
        int p = jt.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
        DefaultTableModel t2 = (DefaultTableModel) tabelaDatoteka_T.getModel();
        String s = (String) t2.getValueAt(p, 1);

        File file = new File(s);
        Desktop des = Desktop.getDesktop();
        try {
            des.open(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Edit: The first column contains the ID, and the file path is found via that ID.

Answer (score 0):

Most paths only show where the file is located, but also do not enter the file name, so you cannot open it because you are essentially opening a folder.